# Angular 2 + Lazyloaded Module is being overridden by an imported module

Tags: angular, angular2-modules

I would like to know how to import a module without it taking priority over the parent module. I am trying to understand why my imported module is overriding the parent modules entry component. I import the `QuotesModule` into my `CompaniesModule` so that it's components are available to my `CompaniesModule`. When the `QuotesModule` is imported as shown here:

`CompaniesModule (lazyloaded)`

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: CompaniesComponent}
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        CreateCompanyComponent,
        CompaniesComponent
    ],
    providers: [
    ],
    imports: [
        QuotesModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        GlobalModule,
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(ROUTES)
    ],
    exports: [
    ],
    schemas: [
        CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        CompaniesComponent
    ]

})
```

...and I attempt to navigate to `CompaniesComponent` route, the `QuotesModule` entry component resolves instead. Any insight would be much appreciated!

Here is my `QuotesModule` Routes and NgModule:

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: QuotesComponent}
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        QuotesComponent
    ],
    providers: [
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        GlobalModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(ROUTES)
    ],
    exports: [
    ]

})
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but that sounds like a router problem. If the component is otherwise properly imported (lazy or otherwise), all should be well.

Comment: You are right! I noticed that the import Module shares an identical router path. And changing them fixes the problem. I'll edit the question to put in the other module and routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will post as answer then (based on above comments)...

...the problem sounds like your router, not the lazy loaded modules (depending on if those modules are in fact loading correctly). Check that the child routes vs. main routes aren't overwriting each other.

And glad to have helped. Tracking down router issues can be a bear.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the routing. I had used different paths to lazy load my `QuotesModule` independently of the `CompanyModule` and when imported,`QuotesModule`'s routes matched and then overwrote the importing modules routes.